# BigQuery Outer Join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables like these:

```
| id | A|
| ---| --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 40 |
```

```
| id | B |
| ---| ---|
| 3 | 1|
| 4 | 2|
| 5 | 3|
| 6 | 4|
```

and I want this by using sql in bigquery:

```
| id | A    | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1|10|null|
| 2|20|null|
| 3|30|1|
| 4|40|2|
| 5| null|3|
| 6| null|4|
```

Comment: The official [query reference for BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins) says: > BigQuery supports INNER, LEFT OUTER and CROSS JOIN operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a full outer join, assuming you are using Standard SQL:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
    t1.A,
    t2.B
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id);
```

Note that for the `id` we report whichever value from either table is not `NULL`, using the `COALESCE` function.  Assuming neither table contains `NULL` values for the `id`, it should be guaranteed that at least one of the two tables has a non `NULL` value for the `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another - least verbose version (*following Gordon's one*)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
USING (id)
```

As you can see, when you use USING(id) there is no ambiguity error being raised for `id` column - as it would if you use `ON t1.id = t2.id` (as in Tim's version)
Note: this assumes `id` is the only common column in those tables and rest of the columns are uniquely named - as it is in your example

Answer (score 1):

You want a `full join` (as Tim points out).  I recommend the `using` clause in this case:

```
SELECT id, t1.A, t2.B
FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     table2 t2
     USING (id)
ORDER BY id;
```